# Anaconda/conda/python/Windows: how to start and activate a conda environment?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

I have Python 3.5 (3.5.6) installed via Anaconda, and now I'd like to be able to use Python 3.7, keeping 3.5 as the default (the one `python "insert script name"` would run on the command line). I commanded the computer to activate it, but it isn't working.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda create --name seiska python=3.7
WARNING: A space was detected in your requested environment path
'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\seiska'
Spaces in paths can sometimes be problematic.
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\seiska

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.7


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0
    certifi:         2018.10.15-py37_0
    openssl:         1.1.1a-he774522_0
    pip:             18.1-py37_0
    python:          3.7.1-he44a216_5
    setuptools:      40.6.2-py37_0
    vc:              14.1-h0510ff6_4
    vs2015_runtime:  14.15.26706-h3a45250_0
    wheel:           0.32.3-py37_0
    wincertstore:    0.2-py37_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate seiska
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > deactivate
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> activate seiska
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: If 3.6 works, this means 3.7 is still not available. Besides, I wouldn't use 64-bit Python unless I know I need it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Why not use 64-bit Python?

Comment: @darthbith Because many packages rely on ctypes and their shared libraries are only precompiled for 32-bit.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Interesting. I've been using 64-bit Conda for ~5 years now and not had any problems with incompatibility, but I don't use that wide a variety of packages. Besides, the entire Anaconda distribution with some hundreds of packages are all compiled for 64-bit. Which packages are you thinking of?

Comment: @darthbith I remember pyqt or pyside caused problems for me on 64-bit. I dealt with lots of packages, but this was like years ago. I can't list accurately what it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Start menu you have to open "Anaconda Prompt" which is different from the Normal "Command Prompt". Your environment gets activated from there.
And then execute `activate <env-name>`

Comment: What Piyush says. Try activating the seiska env from your Anaconda Prompt and then try again. If your not familiair with it already, [this cheat sheet](https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) is very helpful as a backup.

Comment: Yes, that worked. However, in order to use it, I'll either have to open IDLE from \envs\seiska\Scripts\idle.exe or run a Python script using the Anaconda Prompt (and indeed, it's called Anaconda Prompt, not Anaconda Command Prompt) by activating seiska first. The Windows Power Shell works still as described, "activate seiska" does not result in an error, it seems to do nothing, and Python 3.5.6 is the only Python version reachable using the Windows Power Shell. But maybe this is enough for me now.